# Function to Display the time difference in hh:mm:ss for Postgresql DB

Tags: java, postgresql, function, datetime-format

I have the below function which is working for Oracle DB to display the time difference in hh:mm:ss but the same function is not working for the Postgresql DB. There are some syntax issue and unrecognized function issues: Can any one help to convert the below Function in to acceptable format by Postgresql? Pls note this function will be used during runtime and forms the query to DB to return the time in hh:mm:ss

Function:

```sql
RIGHT ('0' + (CAST(
DATEDIFF(hh,CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({1},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},5,2) AS DATETIME), 
CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({2},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},5,2) AS DATETIME))/24 as varchar(10))),2)+':'+
RIGHT ('0' + (CAST((
DATEDIFF(mi,CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({1},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},5,2) AS DATETIME),
CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({2},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},5,2) AS DATETIME))%1440/60) as varchar(10))),2)+':'+
RIGHT ('0' + (CAST(
DATEDIFF(mi,CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({1},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({1},5,2) AS DATETIME), 
CAST('1970-01-01T' +SUBSTRING({2},1,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},3,2)+':'+SUBSTRING({2},5,2) AS DATETIME))%60 as varchar(10))),2)
```

Tried changing the hh to hh24 and DATETIME to TIMESTAMP and reformatted without + operator.

Comment: This code will most certainly not work on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the two timestamps and use to_char() to format the resulting interval:

```
select to_char(justify_interval(timestamp '2022-10-28 14:54:12' - timestamp '2022-10-28 08:18:19'), 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

returns `06:35:53`

The `justify_interval()` isn't strictly necessary especially if you never expect durations longer than 24 hours.

This:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2022-10-28 14:54:12' - timestamp '2022-10-28 08:18:19', 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Would also return `06:35:53`

Comment: So I tried this and during the compile time, this is how the statement is formed: to_char(justify_interval(timestamp "MotorVehicle"."commencedtrip" - timestamp "MotorVehicle"."endtrip"), 'hh24:mi:ss') AS "pyTextValue(1)"  and and throwing error :There was a problem getting a list: code: 0 SQLState: 42601 Message: ERROR: syntax error at or near ""MotorVehicle"" Position: 187

Comment: @VishalNaidu: if you pass a column that is already a timestamp, you don't need the `timestamp` keyword - that is only needed for constant values. So use `"MotorVehicle"."commencedtrip" - "MotorVehicle"."endtrip"`

Comment: Tried it.. but I guess CAST is needed for this one ? because i see there is new error after this one. 0 SQLState: 42883 Message: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying - character varying Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts......  to_char(justify_interval( "MotorVehicle"."commencedtrip" - "MotorVehicle"."endtrip"), 'hh24:mi:ss') AS "pyTextValue(1)"

Comment: **Never** store timestamp values in `varchar` columns. You should fix your table definition before you proceed.